# Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Preview) for Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express, visual-studio-cordova

I tried to install Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Preview). But it says that there must be VS 2013 Update 2. But I have VS 2013 Update 2 (for Desktop, for Windows, for Windows Phone and for Web). Is the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps (Preview) not available for the Express Versions of VS 2013?

Comment: I've added a vote. So everyone who's reading this please vote: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5923747-multi-device-hybrid-apps-with-visual-studio-2013-e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the multi-device hybrid apps preview requires Visual Studio 2013 Professional, Premium, or Ultimate editions, it does not work with the express versions. Please add a vote for it to our http://visualstudio.uservoice.com site if you'd like (while I work on getting a category for this tooling please create the request in the Languages - JavaScript category).

Thank you!

Jordan (Microsoft Visual Studio, JavaScript tools team)